# How extract a substring from string using bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, cut

i want to extract the substring:

```
"1.0.119"
```

From:

```
"/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u"
```

How it can be done?

(i get the whole string from a pipe)

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you explain further what you want to do?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Did you get it with quotes?

Comment: start with `basename` if that is a path. `basename "/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> echo "/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u" | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1-3
1.0.119
```

- `cut -d'-' -f2` returns what is after the first `-`.
- `cut -d'.' -f1-3` returns what is before the third `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the characters between the last `-` and the last `.` with a Bash regex:

```
$ [[ "/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u" =~ [^-]+-(.*)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
1.0.119
```

Or `sed` with the same pattern:

```
$ echo "/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u" | sed 's/^\([^-]*-\)\(.*\)\(\..*$\)/\2/'
1.0.119
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "/abc/efg/v/y-1.0.119.u" | sed 's/\(^.*-\)\(.*\)\(\..*$\)/\2/'
```

Use sed to split the text into three sections, separated with brackets and print just the second section.